# Passing arguments to interactive fortran program

Tags: bash, fortran, interactive

I have a fortran program (which I cannot modify) that requires several inputs from the user (in the command line) when it is run. The program takes quite a while to run, and I would like to retain use of the terminal by running it in the background; however, this is not possible due to its interactive nature.

Is there a way, using a bash script or some other method, that I can pass arguments to the program without directly interacting with it via the command line?

I'm not sure if this is possible; I tried searching for it but came up empty, though I'm not exactly sure what to search for.

Thank you!

ps. I am working on a unix system where I cannot install things not already present.

Comment: Depending on how input is read, piping into stdin might work.

Comment: You can't open up another terminal session to do your non-Fortran work?

Comment: I can open another terminal... but there is A LOT of Fortran work to be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pipe it in:

```
$ cat delme.f90
program delme
    read(*, *) i, j, k
    write(*, *) i, j, k
end program delme

$ echo "1 2 3" | ./delme
           1           2           3

$ echo "45 46 47" > delme.input
$ ./delme < delme.input
          45          46          47

$ ./delme << EOF
> 3 2 1
> EOF
           3           2           1
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed, and I had no idea that it was even possible, let alone so simple. I particularly like the second solution.

Comment: Is this answer specific to `fortran 90`?  Or perhaps a specific fortran compiler (`gfortran` vs `f77`).  I have the same question, but am working with some legacy fortran 77 code.

Comment: This is independent of the compiler, it works with the shell. So it would depend on your operating system. Any Linux or MacOS should be fine, but I don't know about Windows.

Comment: You can also use here-strings: `./program <<< 42`. If `program` reads input more than once, you can insert newlines using ANSI C strings `./program <<< $'42\n19'`.