# Using piping in Windows command line to run simple Fortran exe

Tags: windows, cmd, fortran, pipe, gfortran

I have a Fortran executable that takes a couple keyboard inputs before doing a calculation. It works in the terminal entering the inputs, but I want to using piping to enter the inputs (Windows 10 command line). When I only have one keyboard input, the piping works perfectly. How can I get it to work with multiple inputs?

I can almost get it to work based on a similar question here: [Passing arguments to interactive fortran program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30315213/passing-arguments-to-interactive-fortran-program). I reviewed documentation on standard inputs, but I still can't figure it out.

**Here is an example Fortran program with only one input, and it works with piping.**

```
      program foo
      integer n
      character*80 c
      
      write (*,*) 'Enter 1,2,3 for cat,dog,fish'
      read (*,*) n
      if (n .eq. 1) then
      write (*,*) 'meow'
      elseif (n .eq. 2) then
      write (*,*) 'woof'
      elseif (n .eq. 3) then
      write (*,*) 'blurp'
      else
      write (*,*) 'error1'
      endif
      
C     write (*,*) 'Enter y,n for yay,nay'
C     read (*,*) c
C     if (c == 'y') then
C     write (*,*) 'yes'
C     elseif (c == 'n') then
C     write (*,*) 'no'
C     elseif (n .eq. 3) then
C     else
C     write (*,*) 'error2'
C     endif

      end
```

Terminal test:

```
C:\my\file\path> C:\my\file\path\foo.exe
 Enter 1,2,3 for cat,dog,fish
2
 woof

C:\my\file\path> echo 1 | C:\my\file\path\foo.exe
 Enter 1,2,3 for cat,dog,fish
 meow
```

**Here is an example Fortran program with multiple inputs, and it doesn't work with piping.**

Same program as above, but commented lines are uncommented. Terminal test:

```
C:\my\file\path> C:\my\file\path\foo.exe
 Enter 1,2,3 for cat,dog,fish
3
 blurp
 Enter y,n for yay,nay
n
 no

C:\my\file\path> echo 1 y | C:\my\file\path\foo.exe
 Enter 1,2,3 for cat,dog,fish
 meow
 Enter y,n for yay,nay
At line 18 of file C:/my/file/path/foo.f (unit = 5, file = 'stdin')
Fortran runtime error: End of file

Error termination. Backtrace:

Could not print backtrace: libbacktrace could not find executable to open
#0  0x318dd91b
#1  0x318d6b34
#2  0x318d355b
#3  0x318d7f6c
#4  0x318e8e9d
#5  0x318d88df
#6  0x318d5190
#7  0x318b1691
#8  0x318f3f93
#9  0x318b13c0
#10  0x318b14f5
#11  0xb9677c23
#12  0xba24d4d0
#13  0xffffffff
```

**Compiler information:**
GNU gfortran, CMake based off [wiki example](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/languages/fortran/ForFortranExample)

Comment: The answer to this depends on how the program works. If it does not have command line parameters or does not take stdin, then it will not work as a "one-liner". There might be some "record and playback" program the would work. This question is not about source code, so it is off-topic for SO. Consult your foo.exe user documentation.

Comment: Please use the [tag:fortran] tag for all Fortran questions. Fortran 90 is just one very old revision of the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows cmd, just you can use a for loop.

```
(for %i in (2 y) do @echo %i)|C:\my\file\path\foo.exe
Enter 1,2,3 for cat,dog,fish
woof
Enter y,n for yay,nay
yes
```

If you are putting this in a .bat or .cmd, remember to use two % signs.  There are lots of ways of doing this.  See [How can I echo a newline in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-i-echo-a-newline-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You have two simple read statements. Each reads one record = one line of text. You need to provide two records or let the program continue at the old record.

In [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) I can do `echo -e "2 \n  y" | ./a.out` to get two records into [one `echo` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467424/echo-newline-in-bash-prints-literal-n?rq=1), but I am not sure about Windows cmd. In Powershell you should use [Echo newline to powershell console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737410/echo-newline-to-powershell-console). That means

```
echo "2 `n y"
```

If you can change your Fortran code, use non-advancing input:

```
read (*,'(i1)',advance="no") n
```

With this change I can do

```
> echo -e "2 y" | ./a.out 
 Enter 1,2,3 for cat,dog,fish
 woof
```

Tested in bash, but should work elsewhere including cmd.